# Redis:Error writing to the AOF file: Quota exceeded

Tags: redis

When we run the performance test, we get error from Reids log:

11:M 06 Jun 03:26:02.640 # Bad message length or signature received from Cluster bus.

11:M 06 Jun 03:26:25.429 # Bad message length or signature received from Cluster bus.

11:M 06 Jun 03:26:25.434 # Bad message length or signature received from Cluster bus.

11:M 06 Jun 03:26:27.031 # Error writing to the AOF file: Quota exceeded

could someone help me?

Comment: Where do you run this test? You hit some limit, like cgroups limit or maybe other. Also, what file system do you use?

Comment: we recreate the cluster, it's ok now